# Firebase DB not possible to update, only works in debug mode

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I have a react-native app which figures out if a user allows Firebase Cloud Messaging and then saves the users Token. It also saves the users GeoLocation around this same time.

These functions both work fine if debug mode is enabled on my emulator. However, if debug mode is not running I receive a permission denied warning. Does anyone know why this only works in debug mode?

```
        geoFire.set(uid, [userLocation.lat, userLocation.lng]);
```

Above code should save the location. (This works with debug mode enabled).

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyAZxxxxxxx',
    authDomain: 'thxxxxxx',
    databaseURL: 'https://thxxxxxxx',
    storageBucket: 'thxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
}

// Initialize Firebase
const Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

I use realtime database with the following access rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

I found that a lot of users got this warning message/problem because the rights of the database are not correct. However I double-checked these with the Firebase manual and they should work like this (tested in the Rules Playground in the firebase console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permission denied error means that security rules rejected the query.  If the only rules for your app are what's shown here, it means that there is no user signed in to the app at the time of the query.

Comment: Well I do have a signed in user, with tokens and refreshtokens etc. But all my other queries I make to the database are with http links in which I place the user tokens and all this Works. How should I sign in a user to be able to make the Geofire set commando work for instance?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you saying that you're using the REST API to make requests to the database instead of the provided SDK?  The REST API has its own way of specifying the authenticated user, and you will need to follow the documentation to make that happen.

Comment: Sorry no, I have two functions that are not working with the REST API. These work as they should. So I guess I have to figure out how I can authenticate a user with the react-native-firebase package then?

Comment: Yes, that's a requirement for using the rules that you have now.

Comment: So I finally went further with this problem, but I can't find in the documentation how I should handle this. I have the token and refreshtoken in Async storage. When opening the app it checks if the token is valid, if not it fetches a new token with the refreshtoken. 

However I can't find a function that lets me sign in a user with just the token/refreshtoken/userId or something. Users are not signing into the app all the time because the tokens are valid. Is there such a function to login users with just the token and ID or something?